# Приподвыподвернуться

Tags: значение-слов, лексика

*Из-под пригорка, из-под подвыподверта зайчик **приподвыподвернулся**.*

А что именно сделал зайчик в этой скороговорке? Что означает слово **приподвыподвернуться**?

Comment: Даже моя буйная фантазия тут пасует)))) Представляется какой-то фарш из бедного зайчика или зайчик, согнутый в виде невообразимой фигуры))))))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Мне кажется, что здесь не так важно значение. Важна труднопроизносимость самого слова и сопутствующих (путем нагромождения приставок). Это как раз то, что нужно для  хорошей скороговорки. Есть еще "штаны с исподвыподвертом". Тоже не совсем понятно, что же это за оригинальный фасон (деталь, элемент) штанов...
   С уверенностью можно сказать, что это нечто запутанное, вычурное, необычное. Примерно так. И заяц, выскочив из какого-то подозрительного места под пригорком, сделал какой-то оригинальный кульбит, описать который обычными словами сложно (и не нужно)